# SwiftUI: Multiple LazyVGrid weird scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an issue using the code below, which i cannot explain. It seems to work perfectly when scrolling up and down. The moment you try to rotate this it seems to stutter and not be able to use the old reused cells (Leaving large gaps on the screen which only get fixed by scrolling back up)

Did anyone else experience this behaviour?

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let teaser: String
}

struct BasicCell: View {

    let item: Item

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Color(.gray)
                .cornerRadius(4)
                .aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 361, height: 217), contentMode: .fit)
            Text(item.title)
                .padding(.top, 12)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            Text(item.description)
                .padding(.top, 8)
            Text(item.teaser)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .padding(.top, 10)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ThreeGridLarge: View {

    let header: String
    let items: [Item]

    var columns: [GridItem] {
        [
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 217), spacing: 24, alignment: .leading),
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 217), spacing: 24, alignment: .leading),
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 217), spacing: 24, alignment: .leading)
        ]
    }

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                BasicCell(item: item)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GridView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Group {
                ThreeGridLarge(header: "", items: [
                    Item(title: "GEMEENTERAADSVERKIEZINGEN", description: "Diefstal, bedreiging, geruïneerde zakenpartners: de twee gezichten van ondernemer Willem Blijdorp", teaser: "Willem Blijdorp is een mediaschuwe, maar gevierde ondernemer die geroemd wordt om zijn successen. Geruïneerde ex-zakenpartners vertellen een ander verhaal. „Ik voel me zakelijk vermoord door Blijdorp.”"),
                    Item(title: "MEDIA", description: "Rechter verbiedt uitzending EenVandaag", teaser: "De zitting vond achter gesloten deuren plaats. Zowel de orde van advocaten als EenVandaag mogen geen mededelingen doen over de inhoud van de zaak."),
                    Item(title: "ZWARE MISHANDELING", description: "Lil Kleine opnieuw vast na beroep OM tegen vrijlating", teaser: "Rapper Lil Kleine wordt verdacht van zware mishandeling. Hij kwam twee weken geleden vrij. Het OM zag voldoende „ernstige bezwaren” om hem langer vast te houden en in dat oordeel ging de rechtbank vandaag mee."),
                ])
                .padding(.top, 45)
                ThreeGridLarge(header: "", items: [
                    Item(title: "GEMEENTERAADSVERKIEZINGEN", description: "Diefstal, bedreiging, geruïneerde zakenpartners: de twee gezichten van ondernemer Willem Blijdorp", teaser: "Willem Blijdorp is een mediaschuwe, maar gevierde ondernemer die geroemd wordt om zijn successen. Geruïneerde ex-zakenpartners vertellen een ander verhaal. „Ik voel me zakelijk vermoord door Blijdorp.”"),
                    Item(title: "MEDIA", description: "Rechter verbiedt uitzending EenVandaag", teaser: "De zitting vond achter gesloten deuren plaats. Zowel de orde van advocaten als EenVandaag mogen geen mededelingen doen over de inhoud van de zaak."),
                    Item(title: "ZWARE MISHANDELING", description: "Lil Kleine opnieuw vast na beroep OM tegen vrijlating", teaser: "Rapper Lil Kleine wordt verdacht van zware mishandeling. Hij kwam twee weken geleden vrij. Het OM zag voldoende „ernstige bezwaren” om hem langer vast te houden en in dat oordeel ging de rechtbank vandaag mee."),
                ])
                .padding(.top, 45)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 24)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find an solution that would allow me to use `ScrollView` swapped to a `List` instead and applied alot of fixes to make it look like a plain scrollview.